# Using fluctuating voltage as an input

Tags: arduino-uno

I had an idea to hack a wireless doorbell so it could send notifications to my phone when someone rings the doorbell.

I pulled out the PCB from the doorbell and powered it using the +5v from the Arduino - so far so good

I used the (once was a wire to the speaker) as an analog input

The issue I have is that the voltage for the chime continues for a long time. eg its at 0 before push then it fluctuates for a second, then returns to 519 for a while, before eventually returning to 0.

Is there a smarter way to do this - I have included my code below.

```
void loop()
{
  //detect a changing voltage
  val = analogRead(sensorPin); //pin A0
  delay(500);
  oldVal = analogRead(sensorPin);//pin A0

//if the voltage changed then +1 to the ring counter
  if (val != oldVal) {
      ringCounter = ringCounter+1;
  }

  if (ringCounter > 3 && pinDevid1State == false) // someone pressed the doorbell
  {
    if(DEBUG){Serial.println("pinDevid1 is HIGH");}
    pinDevid1State = true;
    Serial.println("DingDong");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("Notification Sent.");

    //reset vars
    val = 0;
    oldVal = 0;
    ringCounter =0;
  }

  if (ringCounter < 3 && pinDevid1State == true) // the doorbell stopped ringing
  {
    if(DEBUG){Serial.println("pinDevid1 is LOW");}
    pinDevid1State = false;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("DingDongEnd");
    //Sending request to PushingBox when the pin is LOW
    //sendToPushingBox(DEVID1);    //Here you can run an other scenario by creating a DEVID2 variable

    //reset vars
    val = 0;
    oldVal = 0;
    ringCounter =0;

  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve/improve/create? Does this work the way you want it to?

Comment: Expecting two `analogRead()`s half a second apart not to differ at all isn't realistic, I think.  Low order bits fluctuate a lot if there's any electrical noise at all in your system.

Comment: @jwpat7your right but the way the logic works is most of the time they are the same... Its only when the door bell is pressed that it then is consistently different for 30 seconds - hence the ring counter

Comment: @JRobert It does do what I want it to do - I just wondered if there was a more intelligent way to trigger a notification from a change in voltage. I guess my issue is there will be positive voltage while the speaker wire tries to power the speaker. I wonder if there is another pin on the board I could read - I want the bell to responsive to people impatiently pressing = multiple notifications and fast so there is as little delay as possible

Comment: I will try with an hysteresis,

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if there is another pin on the board I could read

I guess that would depend on the particular doorbell. The transmitter must send some representation of a button press to the receiver - a pulse train for the duration of the press, or perhaps just CW: carrier on, carrier off - which the receiver somehow passes on to trigger the audio. Look at the receiver's output side to identify that trigger signal and pass it, or a processed version of it, to the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if there is another pin on the board I could read

You could try to hook up a multimeter to the pins/leads from the doorbell button. Positive to doorbell button pin, negative to power supply ground/doorbell battery.

Once you figure out which pin has voltage when the doorbell button is pressed, you can have that go into a digital or analog input in the Arduino. Make sure that the ground from the doorbell PCB and the Arduino are connected so that they'll have common ground and it should be detectable.